# Mule Dataweave Assertion Function haveKey is not validating keys with null values

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, munit

Does anyone know if the DW Assertions Function haveKey is expected to validate a key pair with the key value being null? It seems MUnit fails the assertion if the value is null as shown below:

```
Expected: to contain key carelineId
Actual: {
carelineId: null
}
at org.mule.munit.assertion.internal.AssertModule.assertMatcherResult(AssertModule.java:77
```

Pretty clear that the key is there, but its value is **null**. Thanks!

**Edit:**

The input is a Transform Message set variable:

```
%dw 2.0 output application/java  
import * from dw::test::Asserts   
--- 
{
   carelineId: null 
}
```

and the expression is:

```
import * from dw::test::Asserts  
---  
vars.theInput must haveKey('carelineId')
```

Comment: What's the actual expression and the input, including the input's class? Which Mule and Munit versions?

Comment: Thank you for checking this. 
The input is a Transform Message set variable:
`%dw 2.0
output application/java

import * from dw::test::Asserts 

---
{
  carelineId: null
}`
and the expression is:
`import * from dw::test::Asserts 
---
 vars.theInput must haveKey('carelineId')`

I have edited the post with these too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that haveKey() uses as a parameter a matcher, not a string. Example:

```
#[MunitTools::hasKey(MunitTools::equalTo('myKey'))
```

See the docs https://docs.mulesoft.com/munit/2.3/munit-matchers

Note that these are Munit assertions and matchers.

Comment: Thank you for this update. I haven't checked this but solved the issue by running the MUnit tests on the latest patched runtime (4.3.0-20210915). It seems this issue was fixed in a previous patch but the MUnit tests were running on the first released 4.3.0 runtime with no patch, hence failing.